# How to execute a process and change the 0th argument?

Tags: java, exec, processbuilder

I'm trying to do something basically like `exec -a` in bash, change the 0th argument that gets passed to a program. However, I don't see any way to do this with ProcessBuilder. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: isn't 0th argument the name of the program itself?

Comment: @nafas typically yes, but it can be changed when using the exec* calls from C directly